# read file contents using awk in shell

Tags: shell

here is my input

```
<mydata>
    <parent detail="school1">
        <CHILD attribute="0">0</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="1">1932</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="2">0</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="3">500</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="4">0</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="5">0</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="6">7819</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="7">0</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="8">299</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="9">0</CHILD>
    </parent>
    <parent detail="school2">
        <CHILD attribute="0">1</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="1">7000</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="2">0</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="3">0</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="4">600</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="5">0</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="6">11674</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="7">0</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="8">489</CHILD>
        <CHILD attribute="9">0</CHILD>
    </parent>
</mydata>
```

my current code

```
sed 's|><|>\n<|g' $WORKING_PATH/mydatafile.log |
awk -F'"|<|>' '/parent detail/{p=$3}
               /CHILD attribute/{att=$3;val=$5;
                     if(val>100)print  "child value on " p, "attribute "att,"is at value: "val ,"\n"}'
```

my current output

```
child value on school1 attribute 1 is at value 1932 
child value on school1 attribute 3 is at value 500
...
... 
child value on school2 attribute 1 is at value 7000 
child value on school2 attribute 4 is at value 600
...
...
```

now my requirement is to pass below attribute values into the if condition as an argument

my file contents are

```
attribute0=100
attribute1=60
attribute3=80
attribute4=90
attribute5=100
attribute6=90
attribute7=50
attribute8=80
attribute9=70
```

I need to pass these values as dynamic argument to that condtion and print result as

```
child value on school1 attribute 1 is at value 1932 and threshold is 60
child value on school1 attribute 3 is at value 500 and threshold is 80
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  It would help considerably if you showed us a (small) sample of the main data, and the output expected from that data.  I think you're after something like 'if the value in `$3` matches 'attributeN' and the value in `$5` is larger than the threshold for 'attributeN', then print some information.  If you have any control over the data layout of the attributes, make them space separated. If you don't, edit the file replacing `=` with spaces.  Then you can read the attributes and values with routine `awk` and get the job done.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, yes you are correct.. I am going to update my question accordingly..

Comment: @JohnB: I think that the `sed` is changing things so that an XML close tag, open tag on the same line are split over two lines.  I think that the main data file is `mydatafile.log`, but the sample attribute names and values are in a separate file.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that your file containing attribute names and threshold values is called `thresholds` and you can't get it generated in a different format.  For convenient processing, you need to drop the word 'attribute' from it.  You need '=' to be a field separator, too.

The standard trick for processing the first file differently from the other files is:

```
awk 'FNR == NR { …process first file… }
     FNR != NR { …process other files… }'
```

You can also use `; next` in the action of the first file processing so you don't need the `FNR != NR` condition; it is probably useful here.  Note the use of a full regex to specify the field separators to `awk`; it says 'one or more double quote, less than, greater than, pipe or equal makes up a field separator.

```
sed 's|><|>\n<|g' $WORKING_PATH/mydatafile.log |
awk -F '["<>|=]+' '
    FNR == NR         { gsub(/attribute/, "", $1); level[$1] = $2; next }
    /parent detail/   { p = $3; }
    /CHILD attribute/ { att = $3; val = $4;
                        if (att in level && level[att] < val)
                        {
                          printf "child value on %s attribute %d", p, att
                          printf " is at value %d and threshold is %d\n", val, level[att]
                        }
                      }
    ' thresholds -
```

The `-` (solo dash) argument indicates 'read standard input'.

(I'm not clear why you have the pipe symbols in the field separator list to `awk`, but I left one of them there as you have it.)

For the sample data, the output is:

```
child value on school1 attribute 1 is at value 1932 and threshold is 60
child value on school1 attribute 3 is at value 500 and threshold is 80
child value on school1 attribute 6 is at value 7819 and threshold is 90
child value on school1 attribute 8 is at value 299 and threshold is 80
child value on school2 attribute 1 is at value 7000 and threshold is 60
child value on school2 attribute 4 is at value 600 and threshold is 90
child value on school2 attribute 6 is at value 11674 and threshold is 90
child value on school2 attribute 8 is at value 489 and threshold is 80
```

Tested with both GNU `awk` and Mac OS X (BSD) `awk` with the same output.

Comment: can you please let me know what are %d and %s

Comment: They're format specifiers for `printf`; `%d` means 'print an integer' and `%s` means 'print a string'.  The extra arguments after the format string are used to provide the values for the `%` conversion specifications.

Comment: it showed me syntax error

awk:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ^ syntax error

Comment: Make sure you picked up the correct version; a very early version was missing a double quote.  If the version above (now) gives a syntax error, then you need to quote the full error message, and convince me you've not mistranscribed something in the script.

Comment: awk:     FNR == NR         { gsub(/attribute/, "", $1); level[$1] = $2;next }    /parent detail/   { p = $3; }    /CHILD attribute/ { att = $3; val = $4;                        if (att in level && level[att] < val)                        {                          printf "child value on %s attribute %d", p, att                          printf "is at value %d and threshold is %d\n", val, level[att]                        }                      }
awk:^ syntax error

Comment: this is the error message it is showing, I am not sure what is missing from my end

Comment: Hmmm...I assume that you have newlines in the script; I didn't put the semicolons at the ends of the lines which would need them if you flatten the script into a single line — mainly because I dislike people who try to make everything into one-liners as if 'one-liner' was not a pejorative term.  Can you send me an email (see my profile) with the copy'n'paste of the exact error message? I can't get you into chat, unfortunately.  It would help to identify your platform and the version of `awk` you are using, too.

Comment: Excellent...it worked now
you are correct , I initially thought that is was a single liner code
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to achieve, I recommand to load these parameters in awk with SHELL, and not with a first awk command.

An example:

```
. myFileContent.sh
awk -v attribute0=$attribute0 ' ... '
```